# JavaFX : Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException (even with scenebuilder finding the controller)

Tags: java, javafx

I searched for my problem but didn't find a solution that worked.

I'm currently trying to code an application with JavaFx and I'm trying to load the controller for a FXML file but even though SceneBuilder finds it, Eclipse doesn't.

Here is my FXML file (located in main/resources/ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="homeScreenAnchorPane" prefHeight="544.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.GlobalVueController">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="431.0" prefWidth="685.0" />
      <ScrollBar layoutX="686.0" layoutY="116.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="431.0" prefWidth="14.0" />
      <ButtonBar layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="458.0">
         <buttons>
            <TextField fx:id="searchBar" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="491.0" />
         </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
      <Button fx:id="addButtonHS" layoutX="502.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Add" />
      <Button fx:id="supprButtonHS" layoutX="611.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Suppr" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="74.0" text="Flitrer par groupe :">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="groupFilter" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="75.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my main Application (where I load the FXML):

```
public class ContactApp extends Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        primaryStage.setTitle("Homescreen");
        StageService.getInstance().setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        showHomeScreen();

    }

    public void showHomeScreen() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(ContactApp.class.getResource("/view/GlobalVue.fxml"));
        System.out.println("bla");
        try {
            AnchorPane rootLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            StageService.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().setScene(scene);
            StageService.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my controller (located in the package view of my application) :

```
public class GlobalVueController {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane homeScreenAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Contact> listView;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchBar;

    @FXML
    private Button addButtonHS;

    @FXML
    private Button supprButtonHS;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Category> groupFilter;

    private ObservableList<Contact> observableContacts;


    public GlobalVueController() {

        observableContacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ContactDao daoContact = new ContactDao();
        daoContact.listAllContacts("").forEach( e-> observableContacts.add(e));

    }


    @FXML
    public void init() {
        listView.setItems(observableContacts);
        listView.setCellFactory(observableContacts -> new ContactViewController());
    }
```

}

And finally the error I get :

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/ISEN/Cours/M1/Projets/Contact_App/contact_app/target/classes/view/GlobalVue.fxml:13

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at isen.java2.app.ContactApp.showHomeScreen(ContactApp.java:38)
    at isen.java2.app.ContactApp.start(ContactApp.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: view.GlobalVueController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 18 more
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I just needed to update my Maven project !